# Convert between char and character when use stack structure java

Tags: java, char, stack, character, peek

I am using a stack to convert infix to postfix expression. I declared `cur=input.charAt(i)`. I want to check if cur is a number. If so, I will add it to the end of the String postfix. I wrote the code:

```
String nonNumbers= "+_*/()"
while (!nonNumbers.contains(s.peek().charValue())){
                       postFixExp=postFixExp+cur;}
```

As the chars I pushed into the stack were automatically converted to character objects(I guess), so I used charValue() to get the char from the stack and see if the string nonNumbers contains this char.

But I got error message " error: cannot find symbol
                       while (!nonNumbers.contains(s.peek().charValue())){
                                                           ^
  symbol:   method charValue()
  location: class Object" when tried to compile.Can someone please help me with this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: did you really forget to to close the first line included here with a semicolon? If so, are you using an IDE (which would have alerted you to this error)? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

Method contains() can not be applied to character arguments. It has to be a CharSequence, meaning you can pass the objects of type string or stringbuffer to it. I would suggest using

```
s.peek().toString();
```

instead of

```
s.peek().charValue()
```

Comment: The elements in the stack are not integers, but chars, I dont think we can use toString() here?